# Squeeze the neck of a t-shirt

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

My aim is make the neck area more narrow

**Before:**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Currently I am tring to achieve this with liquify, but the results I achieve are not very succesful. Is there a better option to change the neck?

**Edit:** To Clarify the problem better, What I am tring to narrow down is not the neck of the person, it is the neck of the t-shirt. I am t-shirt seller and the t-shirts that I sell have necks like the one in second picture, but my t-shirt template looks like the first one, so I am tring to make my template look like the t-shirt in the second one.

**Edit 2** I am uploading my current template (PSD), and the possible candidate JPGs which I want to achieve a similar look. [Click to download.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwHDkPOX-lRtdWFPdi0tcDFOX28?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Your additions make my original answer ridiculous. Even the one single word that I seem to have guessed right is in totally wrong context.

Seriously:

The PSD composition over the base photo in the template is a respectable piece of pro quality work. Messing only around the collar probably will destroy it - at least, if you want to use it in the original resolution. In addition it would be idiotic to change the collar. It affects in so many places that it's much easier to change the whole shirt.

Your high quality solution is to rebuild the PSD around your new base photo. If you can understand the details in your PSD, you are able to do it yourself. If not, you must hire a pro and be ready to pay half a day. All layers, masks and colors must be adapted to be based on the new photo.

The job can be substantially reduced if you do not use all features of the PSD template. But the job still needs understanding the layers.

ADDENDUM: Just in case you need something just now, you can try one of my trials on the same concept. I put into it your "Yellow candidate" from your links. Of course it's a fast crunch and much simpler, but also has something nonexistent in your loose hanging template. Adjust layer opacities to see what they do.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qza57yvz1lkbpms/T_Shirt_287001.psd?dl=0

[image]

===========================

**THINNING THE NECK - THE OBSOLETE ANSWER **
I see the problem. You want quite heavy thinning and liquifying easily spoils the perfect round shape of the collar. In additon there may have existed some reason that prevented the thinning before the photo session.

One solution is to clip the top part of the shirt to another layer and use it to cover the distorted collar. Use Edit > Transform tools to

- reduce the size of the clip
- warp the clip to fit to shoulders and the thinned neck

Add a layer mask to the clip and fade the edges to get rid of steep color difference at the outer edge of the clip.

This is the thinning without the new collar

[image]

This is the added new collar:

[image]

And this is the final result:

[image]

Comment: Hi , I didn't why you used the second picture,  What I am tring to narrow down is not the neck of the person, it is the neck of the t-shirt. I am t-shirt seller and the t-shirts that I have sell have necks like the one in second picture, but my t-shirt template looks like the first one, so I am tring to make my template look like the t-shirt in the second one.

Comment: @HOY can you provide a full image that you want to be modified? Is it impossible simply to take a new photo? We know nothing about the resolution and actual outlook of your problematic image. All we know is that a collar somewhere (no idea, where) is too big.

Comment: I edited the question and add a download link for the files. @user287001

Comment: @HOY I added something that can be used as first aid

Answer (score 4):

Copy the neck of another t-shirt image and manipulate it onto the original one.