# How can I mockup a custom stripe fabric on a t shirt

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am starting a clothing brand and I want to create mockups of stripe designs that I do in illustrator so I can have a realistic look at them. I tried many psd mockup templates but none of them enabled me to do the all over stripe pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: In which way doesn't the templates enable you to do the "all over stripe pattern"? Is it the stripes you need help for? Or is it masking your artwork, so it covers the t-shirt, but stays within the bounds of the t-shirt?

Comment: insert a draft of what you expect and some photos of the cloths. Because you have been around a short time, you cannot insert many images, so add a download link. We have no idea how complex is your problem.  General graphic software run soon out of the steam, if there's foldings and waves that must be taken into the account when adding the glaze. In this question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94671/squeeze-the-neck-of-a-t-shirt  there's a simple case and its solution. Obviously you want something more complex. Let us know, how complex.

Comment: @Wolff the templates only have a certain work area, e.g 12" x 6". Where as the stripes would be all over the shirt. I am sure you have seen a striped shirt before :).

Comment: @user287001I'm not sure what I expect, I just want to see what my stripe patterns look like on a shirt. Likes [this](https://imgur.com/a/iSV3s)

Comment: @PhizzleMcDizzle Actually this should be enough for an answer - only a writer is needed. When waiting it check a link in the answer that is given to the question I wrote in my previous comment. It has no artwork square, it can be full size.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into Photoshop "Transparency Masks".

Here is one way to do it, out of many:

- Take an image of a t-shirt.
  [image: A t-shirt.]
- Select the t-shirt. Here I've just used `Quick Selection Tool`, but you could use any method you like. Use `Refine Edge` to fine tune the selection if you want.
  [image: The t-shirt is now selected.]
- Create a new `Group`, click the `Mask` button to convert the active selection of the t-shirt to a mask on the group. Set the `Blend Mode` of the group to "Multiply".
  [image: A masked group.]
- Now, everything you put inside the group is confined to the shape of the t-shirt. The "Multiply" blend mode makes the colors of the group tint the underlying t-shirt instead of covering it.
  [image: Coloring is confined to the shape of the t-shirt.]

The mask is a grayscale image, shown as a thumbnail to the right of the group symbol/layer thumbnail. The darker the mask gets, the more transparent the content of the layer it is applied to gets. And the whiter it gets, the more opaque.

The mask can be clicked and then edited. If you `ALT-CLICK` the mask, you enter "mask mode" where the mask is displayed in grayscale. Click the layer thumbnail to return to "normal mode".

Always pay attention to the smoothness/raggedness of the contours in your mask, since they define how well your layer blends together with the rest of the image.

Comment: Side note: Please don’t ever actually make a t-shirt with that print. For the sake of humanity.

Comment: If that shirt were available somewhere with few bucks, I would order one. I am not the master of fine taste, but this overrides me 400%.

Comment: @Janus, lol! I accidentally created a weapon of mass destruction.

Answer (score 1):

If the canvas patterns are only as computer files, you can well present them on a shirt with illustrations. Real canvas would have rich details which unfortunately are unknown. So do not guess them. Take proper photos after you have something physical. After that you can also make some fake photos as mockups when you know how your ideas get materialized (=how your patterns get bended and folded along the canvas)

Here's an example:

[image]

A coarse shirt was drawed with the pen in Illustrator. Only a half was made because L-R symmetry was assumed. The shirt was thought to be without any bumps and foldings. I do not know much about textiles, so this is based on guessing and some low quality T-shirt photos that I have seen in the web.

The different canvas pieces were colored with the live paint tool to get closed shapes. The line drawing was moved aside.

A simple stripe pattern  was generated as a bunch of rectangles. The white is not full 100%, but about 90% to leave some room for highlights and keeping it a little different than white background.

Two copies of the half shirt, the other flipped, were aligned. Some pieces got solid grey fill color and 3 pieces got the drawed stripe shape (rotate and clip as needed, clip is made with Object > Path > Divide Objects Below).

Clipping masks can be useful and also having the canvas pattern as fill swatch. They are not used here.

The final illustration can have some 3D-like forms. The colored shirt was warped and shaded to look out a little more random and to have some bumps and bends.

[image]

This phase was done experimentally in Serif Affinity Photo which seems to have an excellent warp tool. The shading is some blurred black and white strokes in a new layer which has reduced opacity and blending mode = Hard light. The exessive blur was deleted by making a selection with the warped shirt. Blurred black and white work also in Illustrator, but there's more handy tool for this: The gradient mesh.

This can seem complex, but the deformations are arbitary. I wasn't forced to slavishly copy anything existing. That's why the warping and shading took only few minutes. Foldings and wrinkles are a lightyear more difficult, so they are skipped.

All presented can be done in Illustrator, which has a big advantage: You can edit or change shapes and patterns behind  envelope distortion mesh. That makes possible a template that needs only to change the canvas pattern and colors to get a new shirt. Geometric forms including bends and bumps stay, if wanted.

Shadings and color and light adjustments are easy to reuse in Photoshop and several others, but I have not found a practical way to reuse envelope distortion in other software than Illustrator. But, as written, simple deformations can be done from scratch in a couple of minutes.

For cloth designer's there exists 3D modelling software which can create realistic foldings and wrinkles. Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3xrkMhKwII to see what is possible, if one can pay the price. There are several others, too.