# Tool to see how my logo look like on clothes , websites , booklet and bags

Tags: adobe-indesign, logo

Is there any tool which can help me to check how my logo will looks like on certain goods like booklets , bags and clothes ?

Comment: Yeah that would be any software capable of conposing images. Like photoshop.

Comment: I think probably the tool that offers the most options in one place is probably: [PlaceIt.net](https://placeit.net/) (If you know how to attach files in an email, you'll be able to use this service) — There are also places that sell mockups among other things: [Creative Market](https://creativemarket.com/search?q=apparel+mockup&categoryIDs=0), [Graphic River](https://graphicriver.net/brochure+mockup-in-graphics) ← These will usually be psd files where you swap in your own graphic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to insert a shape with solid color to a photo, that can be done in any photo editing program.

Obviously you want more: You need a general tool which knows common product types, geometric surface forms, materials and common ways to insert things to them, for ex. you only select a leather covered book from the menu and the tool automatically places your logo as gold foil stamped & embossed to the wanted place in the wanted size. As well only a few clicks and your logo is shown as embroidered on a high end jacket or as carved into a golden watch.

Ultimately you want also insert your our own product photos and the logo will be inserted onto them automatically without any complex definitions and the job is done with the same care as to the included items.

Unfortunately no software still is this clever because it should remember and fully understand nearly all things that people wear or use. Software that understands something, is still a dream (or nightmare).

I'm afraid you must do as already suggested ie. buy mockup kits. They are complex multilayer Photoshop files. You insert your images to certain layers and it's there. You cannot change the main image except by rebuilding the whole mockup.

Many mockups are available also for free, but their quality vary radically.

Constructing mockups needs good image processing skills and creating one can take days or only one hour depending on the complexity of the case. The more it has variations and adjustability, the more complex file you must compose.

I must admit that there exists some attempts which include so many mockups with so many variation possiblities that it resembles the miracle machine I described in the beginning. One of them is Adobe's Dimension. You can try it for free.

What makes it so difficult? It's the need of plausibility. The inserted shape must look out like it is made of real material and it was there when the photo was taken. It's generally much more than adding a new layer with fresh text and image.

Start by reading this older discussion: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

This old case started from the need of a shrinked neck, but it leads to 2 mockups. [Squeeze the neck of a t-shirt](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94671/squeeze-the-neck-of-a-t-shirt)